# Why doesn't grep match a forward-slash at word boundaries (e.g. `/baz` in `import baz from './foo/bar/baz';`)?

Tags: regex, grep

In my project, I'm trying to match files that contain "/baz". So, I do the following:

```
grep -rnw . -e "\/baz"
```

The output correctly matches the following instance:

```
import { baz } from './baz';
```

But it does not seem to match on this line:

```
import { baz } from './foo/bar/baz';
```

It does match if I grep on `"bar\/baz"`, however. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the `-w` argument from your `grep` call. From `grep` help:

> -w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words

It will, therefore, match your pattern only if it's a whole word (surrounded by word boundaries such as a dot, whitespace, begin/end of the line...)

Comment: Great! Thanks buddy. I'll mark yours as the answer, since it includes the man page.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
grep -rn . -e "\/baz"
```

without the `word` flag. Otherwise the expression looks for word boundaries which cannot be found in the second example.

Comment: Great! Thanks buddy.